# UserType Entity linking with Different POJO

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am implementing a spring boot application where I am using Postgres Database. My table structure will be something like this

```
 id   | data
--------------------------------------------------
 1     | {"name":"AlexRob", 
       |  "emailid":"alexrob@hotmail.cocm",
          "city" : Texas}
--------------------------------------------------
 3     | {"name":"Janice", 
       |  "emailid":"janice@hotmail.cocm",
          "city" : Mexico,
           "Link" : "OutSource"}
--------------------------------------------------
```

So id will be Int types but data will be of JSONB type. I have done implementation where data will be one single type of JSON. I created a POJO  and defined a custom type class by implementing the UserType interface from hibernate. and then created an entity class where typedef was used as my own UserType.It works fine.
But the problem is my data of the table is not a consistent JSON. It will vary depending upon what user inputs. I can create multiple POJO but it's like doing all things again for each id. Defining UserType again and creating a separate Entity for each column. Even at controller, I have to write separate Rest APIs for all id's.
Is there a better approach to solve this?
I am using hibernate and Postgres DB.
I am adding few POJO classes and UserType classes which I have already implemented.

```
public class AlexRob implements Serializable {

    private String emailid;
    private String city;

    public String getEmailid() {
        return emailid;
    }

    public void setEmailid(String emailid) {
        this.emailid = emailid;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
-------------------
public class Janice implements Serializable {

    private String emailid;
    private String city;

    public String getLink() {
        return Link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        Link = link;
    }

    private String Link;
    public String getEmailid() {
        return emailid;
    }

    public void setEmailid(String emailid) {
        this.emailid = emailid;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
-----------------
//Custom UserType classes are defined for these by implementing UserType interface from hibernate.
public class JaniceType implements UserType {
    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[]{ Types.JAVA_OBJECT };}

    @Override
    public Class<Janice> returnedClass() {
        return Janice.class;
    }
//more overrided methods
------------
public class AlexRobType implements UserType {
    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[]{ Types.JAVA_OBJECT };}

    @Override
    public Class<AlexRob> returnedClass() {
        return AlexRob.class;
    }
//Now I have defined entities for each UserType class Like below

@Entity
@Table(name = "information",schema = "public")
@TypeDef(name = "AlexRobType",typeClass = AlexRobType.class )
public class AlexRobImpl {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "data")
    @Type(type = "AlexRobType")
    private AlexRob alexrob;
    
    //getter and setters 
-------------
@Entity
@Table(name = "information",schema = "public")
@TypeDef(name = "JaniceType",typeClass = JaniceType.class )
public class JaniceImpl {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "data")
    @Type(type = "JaniceType")
    private Janice janice;
    
    //getter and setters
```

Now I can all them separately from the controller and it works fine but I want to have a single controller where I will define my API's and values will be set according to id.

Comment: Can you please add some of the relevant classes to your question? Additionally, what does "It will vary depending upon what user inputs" mean? Do you mean having a different set of attributes?

Comment: Thanks for the help :) . From the given table data, you can see that with id=1 I have some JSON data but with id =3, the data is a bit different.  The data fields are actually POJO classes here.  Now I have to generalize class implementing UserType and Entity so that they can handle this.

Comment: If you could add the POJOs it would be useful so that we understand the number of different properties so that we can suggest a possible approach.

Comment: Sure @JoãoDias, I have added the whole implementation in the question.

Comment: Why don't you have a class that contains all the needed properties for all user types? Do you really need to have separate classes representing this?

Comment: Yes, I need separate classes. There will be many different classes but few parameters will be common but others will be totally different. So it's a must for me.

Comment: Can't you simply create a common abstract class called `User` from which all your other User types would extend?

Comment: So you are suggesting I will create an abstract class User with all possible properties and then my User Types will extend it and I can use that abstract class to actually interact with  hibernate while creating customer UserType and in Entities. right?

Comment: I wouldn't include all the possible properties, but then again, I am really confused about what you are trying to achieve here. What is exactly your use case? Why do you need to have so many different user types?

Comment: I have to save this Data into Postgres DB and whenever required, I will get those data from my POJO classes. My data wont be much big as I will have a max of 10 rows. But I really want to implement it in this common way.

Comment: If you want to map all these JSONs(considering all are different) to POJOs and you are going to create each type of POJO then you can also save the type of POJO (full class name) into DB column itself and then you may use reflection and Jackson to parse back it to POJO.